# Python: Binomial distribution doesn't work when set as a variable

Tags: python, variables, environment-variables, scoping, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to recreate a single player version of a dice game called Dudo. The most relevant information is that six players have six hidden dice, and the point of the game is to guess how many of a certain kind of die are on the table in total (e.g. If there are ten 4s, or twelve 5s etc).

To make some AI, I'm using binomial distributions where the computer guesses the probability of there being a certain number of a certain kind of die, based on how many of that kind of die it already has in its hand. I saved this equation in the variable chance:

```
chance = ((1/3) ** (i - player_dice_type[turn][active_type])) * ((2/3) ** (total_count - i - player_count[turn] + player_dice_type[turn][active_type]))
```

`i` is the number of that kind of die (e.g. six 5s, or seven 5s, or eight 5s etc.). I have a list of how many of each kind of die a player has (`player_dice_type`) and I can select a specific die for a specific player by subsetting `turn` and `active_type`. The 1/3 has to do with the rules of the game (normally it'd be 1/6 for dice), but that doesn't have to do with my issue anyway.

When I call chance, it ONLY gives me the value for if `player_dice_type[turn][active_type] = 0`, and `i = 6`, so the probability that 6 of that die are on the table when the computer has 0 of it.

I can call `i` and `player_dice_type[turn][active_type]` and see that they do NOT equal 6 or 0. The thing is though, if I copy and paste the equation, it works perfectly fine. It only defaults to 6 and 0 when I call chance.

I've also tried making a `chancefun(i)` function that returns the original equation, and then said `chance = chancefun(i)`. I can change i in the environment to whatever I want and `chancefun(i)` will react accordingly, but once again, the variable `chance` does not.

I've included scoping as a tag just because I think it might somehow be related but I can't think of how. I've also tried change the variable name from `chance` to a bunch of other things and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined `chance` as a variable, its value was fixed when you created it.  It will not "update" if you later change the value of `i` or anything else.  You cannot "call" chance as you've defined it; it's just a static value, not a function.

If you do something like `chance = chancefun(i)`, that *sets* the value of chance, once, and that's it.  Is does not "link" the variable `chance` to `chancefunc` somehow.

If you want to get different values of chance for different parameters, make it a function and call it with the arguments you want.  Something like:

```
def chance(i, turn, active_type):
    return ((1/3) ** (i - player_dice_type[turn][active_type])) * ((2/3) ** (total_count - i - player_count[turn] + player_dice_type[turn][active_type]))
```

I'm assuming here that `player_dice_type` and `total_count` are globally defined variables.  You will need to decide what values you want `chance` to look up globally and which ones you want to pass on each call.

Comment: You're right, thanks. This really stumped me for a while, and just writing it made me realize the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with `chance` calculating a value at the very start and holding onto that value. When everything boots up, i = 6 and player_dice_type is an empty list (it gets filled later with another function). Later, I can type in `chance = chancefun(i)` once I've generated some numbers and changed `i`, and `chance` will display that exact value, but lock on to it again.

I'll probably just continue and use chancefun(i) without using chance, but I thought that it'd be really handy to save everything under one variable called `chance` as later I'd have to be adding up multiple probabilities